# How to allow access from ec2 to beanstalk app?

Tags: security, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I added the beanstalk ec2 instances' security group to the inbound in the other ec2 instance, but it's not working. Both ec2 instance and beanstalk are in the same region. Is there any other restriction?

Comment: Are either of them running inside a VPC?

Comment: All these instances are in the same VPC.